# Why android studio show error: Error:failed to find target Google Inc.:Google APIs:15?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

setting of gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:15'
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "jp.osaka"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 15
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5.0.1438"
    }
```

[image]

I had install and restart Android Studio 2.3.2 and restart PC, but it still can't resolve error.
Why android studio show error: Error:failed to find target Google Inc.:Google APIs:15 ?

Answer (score 0):

compileSdkVersion is supposed to be an integer. In your case, if you want to compile with the sdk version 15 you should do:

```
compileSdkVersion 15
```

Comment: If i write 15 and build. some old lib will occur error (ex: import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;)

Comment: But is there any reason why you don't use the compileSdkVersion 25 (last one)?
You can still have the SDK 15 as targetSdkVersion then.
From the doc (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html):
"compileSdkVersion specifies the Android API level Gradle should use to compile your app. This means your app can use the API features included in this API level and lower."